How to disable loading of (selected) plugins while doing things in Wordpress/Woocommerce
I'm doing quite a number of actions on products in Woocommerce from "outside" Wordpress/Woocommerce, from within a shell-environment, through scripts of my own.
For this, I "load" Wordpress through wp-load.php, to be able to use the Wordpress/Woocommerce-functions and some PHP-includes of my own.
This works quite well and quite a bit faster then "calling" the scripts through a browser/Curl. And this way still has the advantages of approaching the Wordpress/Woocommerce-data through carefully crafted Wordpress/Woocommerce-functions to keep the data "aligned".
But sometimes I get errors from plugins, that I don't use in this environment (and could do without in this environment), but which are loaded of course, when loading the Wordpress environment through wp-load.php.
Is there a simple way, to prevent loading of one or more plugins in this shell-environment (because their functionality isn't used in this shell-environment), without switching those plugins off for the front-end?
I would not know how to prevent loading of some plugins, because I wouldn't know where to start ;-)
I looked at the deactivate_plugins() function, but that seems to deactivate the given plugin(s) for the current site as a whole, and not just in the shell-environment.
